# Turn text into a string of letters in python?

Tags: python, string, list, text

So I am trying to make a piece if code that can take a string, ignore all plain text in it, and return a list of numbers but I am running into trouble.

basically, I want to turn "I want to eat 2 slices of pizza for dinner, and then 1 scoop of ice cream for desert" 
into [2,1]  (just an example)

```
    dummy = dummy.split(" ")
                    j = 0
                    for i in dummy:
                        dummy[j]=i.rstrip("\D")
                        j+=1
                        print(dummy[j-1])
```

is what i have tried but it didn't remove anything. i tried the rstrip("\D") because i thought that was supposed to remove text but does not seem to work for a list.

any ideas where i went wrong or ways to fix this?

Comment: You are confusing ordinary text with regular expressions.

Comment: `\D` is used in a regular expression. `rstrip` and family don't take regular expression as argument, just strings or the special value `None` (the default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like classwork, so try this:

1. Use str.split to divide the sentence into words.
2. Use str.isdigit to determine which words are all digits.
3. Use int() to convert the digit-only words into integers.
4. Return the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.split` for this (slightly along the lines of the code you've posted, where as TigerhawkT3 observes you appear to be mixing up regular expressions with strings) but even better for your purpose is `re.findall`. That plus calling `int` to turn numeric strings into actual integers will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regular expression:

```
import re

string = "I want to eat 12 slices of pizza for dinner, and then 1 scoop of ice cream for desert"
numbers = list(map(int, re.findall(r"\d+", string)))
print(numbers)
#[12, 1]
```

The `str.rstrip()` method, however, does not use regular expressions, so that's why yours didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be something like

```
dummy = [int(c) for c in dummy.split(" ") if c.isdigit() ]
```

This would only pick up numbers separated by spaces on either side though (e..g "2cm" would not be picked up).

Comment: so i added exclude = set(string.punctuation)
                        dummy = ''.join(ch for ch in dummy if ch not in exclude)
                        to the beginning so that it would still pull numbers even with punctuation right after the number thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `re.findall()` method will create a list of matching strings, and a simple list comprehension converts them to `int`s.

```
import re
dummy = "I want to eat 2 slices of pizza for dinner, and then 1 scoop of ice cream for desert"

result = [int(d) for d in re.findall(r'\d+', dummy)]

print(result)
```

gives:

```
[2, 1]
```